# Protractor says that a checkbox is not visible, but it is. How to investigate and fix it?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

So, I have this HTML inside an angular app:

```
<div class="panel">
    <input class="eula" id="eula" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="eula">I agree</label>
</div>
```

And this two expectations on the same spec (just to be sure that there's no other stuff running):

```
expect(element(by.css('.panel')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
expect(element(by.css('.eula')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

First one, is true. Second one is false. That's strange. It should be also true.

So, i try:

```
element( by.css( '.panel' ) ).getOuterHtml()
.then( function ( html ) {
    console.log( html );
});
```

And i get:

```
<input class="eula" id="eula" type="checkbox">
```

From what I see, there's nothing hidding the checkbox so i don't understand why protractor says that is not visible. Is there another way to test this? Any idea on how to proceed to debug and fix it?

Comment: If that was the answer, feel free to enter it as an official answer to this question and accept it when you can.

Comment: Have you tested with the following:

expect(element(by.id('eula')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

Comment: Yes and still doesn't work. Problem was the input with the display: none property. Doesn't matter which selector I use, is still hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From protractor isDisplayed() documentation:**

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

The input had a display: none property, and that was the problem.